# How to set only minutes and seconds using BFormTimePicker from bootstrap-vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, timepicker, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to use the [Form TimePicker](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-timepicker/) to send a time to an api that will have only minutes and seconds.

I tried to set a property format: "mm:ss" but it is not working.

My code:

```
<b-form-timepicker
    id="testDuration"
    v-model="testDuration"
    placeholder="Test duration"
    label-no-time-selected="Set a valid time"
    label-close-button="Fechar"
    format="mm:ss"
/>
```

I would like to know if there is a way of doing it